# Selenium With Eclipse IDE Making Small BOT

Tags: java, eclipse, facebook, selenium

I am  a new student of Computer Science, excuse if I sound n00b.

What I am trying to do is I am trying to make a simple BOT which can login into the facebook and post a Status.
I am doing this with the help of Selenium and Eclipse IDE in JAVA.

The problem is although successfully logs in,

But as my Facebook account is not verified it lands into a verification page.

What I want to do is I want to create an IF condition, such that IF the program finds Verification Page it must click on "Not Now" button
ELSE if the account is already verified it can post status from home page.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why don't you try using the Facebook API instead of Selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait some time to WebElement appears after login for example the WebElement which contains the user's name. If it doesn't appear you know that the other page or a popups appeared on browser.

The RemoteWebDriver has switchTo() method. You can handle popups with this method.

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```

driver variable is a RemoteWebDriver like FirefoxDriver and so on, you navigate an alert window in the above example.

I share you an example code how it should work step by step:

```
public void login(){
     String url="URL"
     driver.get(url);
     WebElement username= driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
     WebElement password= driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
     WebElement loginButton= driver.findElement(By.name("login_button_id"));
     Boolean isLogged=isSuccessFullyLogged(username,password,loginButton)

     if(!isLogged){
             //we need verification
     }
}

public boolean isLoggedSuccessfully(WebElement usr,WebElement psswd,WebElement button){
     if(usr!= null && psswd != null && button != null){
          usr.sendKeys("Blala");
          psswd.sendKeys("Blalaspasswd");
          button.submit();
          //We wait 10 sec to Welcome page appears on screen if it does not appear then  we need verification
          return (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new         ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                 public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                       return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("welcome!");

          });
     }      
}
```

I hope this chunk of code helps you.

Comment: I know that. what i am finding trouble with is if the BOT encounters a verification page there is "Not Now" button which i want it to click.
But if the verification page isn't displayed then i want it to go to ELSE condition and post the status

Answer (score 0):

In selenium you are able to get current url, so you're able to create this condition. What is the problem here?

Comment: How to create If condition from that?

Comment: I know how to create an IF condition. you ain't getting the gist of the question.

I am unable to create IF-ELSE condition for the particular case.
what test to pass into IF?